# Batch to rename files with metadata name

Tags: bash, batch-file, metadata, data-recovery

I recently accidentally formatted a 2TB hard drive mac os jounaled!
I was able to recover files with Data Rescue 3, the only problem is the program didn't gave me the files as they were, root tree, and name.

For example I had

```
|-Music
||-Enya
|||-Sonadora.mp3
|||-Now we are free.mp3
|-Documents
||-CV.doc
||-LetterToSomeone.doc
...and so on
```

And now I got

```
|-MP3
||-M0001.mp3
||-M0002.mp3
|-DOCUMENTS
||-D0001.doc
||-D0002.doc
```

So with a huge amount of data it would take me centuries to manually open, see what is it and rename.

Is there some batch which can scan all my subfolders and take the previous name? By metadata perhaps?

Or do you know a better tool which will keep the same name and path of files (doesn't matter if must pay, ther's always a solution for that :P)

Thank you

Comment: Cannot you just use names from a backup (matched by size and even data, if that was rescued), and manually rename only the files that are not present in the backup (newer or changed)?

Answer (score 4):

My contribution for you music at least...

The idea is to go through all of the MP3 files found, and distributed them based on their ID3 tags.

I'd do something like :

```
for i in `find /MP3 -type f -iname "*.mp3"`;
do
   ARTIST=`id3v2 -l $i | grep TPE1 | cut -d":" -f2 | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//'`; # This gets you the Artist
   ALBUM=`id3v2 -l $i | grep TALB | cut -d":" -f2 | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//'`; # This gets you the Album title
   TRACK_NUM=`id3v2 -l $i | grep TRCK | cut -d":" -f2 | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//'`; # This gets the track ID/position, like "2/13"
   TR_TITLE=`id3v2 -l $i | grep TIT2 | cut -d":" -f2 | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//'`; # Track title
   mkdir -p /MUSIC/$ARTIST/$ALBUM/;
   cp $i /MUSIC/$ARTIST/$ALBUM/$TRACK_NUM.$TR_TITLE.mp3
done
```

Basically :
 * It looks for all ".mp3" files in /MP3
 * then analyses each file's ID3 tags, and parses them to fill 4 variables, using "id3v2" tool (you'll need to install it first). The tags are cleaned to get only the value, sed is used to trim the leading spaces that might pollute.
 * then creates (if needed), a tree in /MUSIC/ with Artist name and album name
 * then copies the input files to the new tree, and renames it thanks to the tags.